# Viewport not going to camera when I click numpad 0

Tags: camera

When I click Numpad 0, The view port normally goes to the camera's perspective

In this picture you can clearly see where the camera is 
[image]

but when I click Numpad 0 to go to the camera's perspective it goes to the center of the skeleton for my model
[image]

If anyone has a way to fix this, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check your input preferences for View Numpad. Maybe you changed it sometime?

Comment: In case anyone else encounters this problem, well, there is a bug i think that makes an armature become the camera. Removing the armature and appending it back from a backup file will stop the issue from happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your camera is not active anymore, select it and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>, or in the *Properties* panel > *Scene* > *Camera* > choose the camera you want.

Comment: If this is the right answer you should mark it as “right” with the green check mark.

Answer (score 0):

The camera in my setting was active but had the same problem. The solution was to move the camera from a nested collection to the "Scene Collection"

[image]